# How to create a regex in ruby to (1)filter out everything after a string and to (2) filter something in the middle of a line?

Tags: ruby, regex

**Case 1:** 
Consider the line:

```
[2014-03-05 17:21:39 -0800] this.computer.name - Select file: f7de1.png
```

I need to filter out everything after "Select file: ". Basically in need the **filename** from a sentence like above.

**Case 2:**
Consider the line:

```
[2014-03-05 17:21:39 -0800] this.computer.name - Cycle: 12345 File: f7de1.png
```

I need to filter the **cycle number** here, which is 12345

For both these cases here, the filename can be different lengths for different cycles.

Comment: what do you mean by filter? do you want to capture `f7de1.png` and remove all other text?

Comment: Oops sry, I am using ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First case:

```
str = "[2014-03-05 17:21:39 -0800] INFO this.computer.name - Select file: f7de1.png"
str[/file: (.+)/, 1]
=> "f7de1.png"
```

Second case:

```
str = "[2014-03-05 17:21:39 -0800] INFO this.computer.name - Cycle: 12345 File: f7de1.png"
str[/Cycle: (\d+)/, 1]
=> "12345"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `scan()` of ruby with regex.

Get the file name:

```
input = '[2014-03-05 17:21:39 -0800] INFO this.computer.name - Select file: f7de1.png'
print input.scan(/select file: (.+\..+)/i)
```

Get the cycle number:

```
input = '[2014-03-05 17:21:39 -0800] INFO this.computer.name - Cycle: 12345 File: f7de1.png';
print input.scan(/Cycle: (\d+) File:/i)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "[2014-03-05 17:21:39 -0800] INFO this.computer.name - Select file: f7de1.png"  
a.match(/Select file: ([\w\d\._-]+)/)[1]

b = "[2014-03-05 17:21:39 -0800] INFO this.computer.name - Cycle: 12345 File: f7de1.png"
b.match(/Cycle: (\d+)/)[1]
```